# change the color of the head of the apk

Tags: java, android

How to automatically change the color of the navigation bar based on the color of my app. For example if the color of my app is blue I want the navigation bar to turn blue automatically

I don’t know what to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done inside styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

Set that to the primaryColor of your app. Requires API 21 or above.

Comment: I’m new so I find some difficulty I now created the file style.xml pasted the code you told me that the first and made app startup but nothing happened

Comment: It won't just work, I would suggest understanding what it is you are trying to do.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes

Comment: I’m trying to make the title bar color equal the color of my app. This I want to be done automatically for example if I try to choose the color of my green color app I want the title bar to be automatically green color, is it possible ?

Comment: It is possible using themes and styles. You define a color palette, assign colors to more ambiguous general definitions such as colorPrimary/ colorOnPrimary etc. Set your themes background color to your colorPrimary then also assign to my original answer snippet. If applied correctly the navigation bar and toolbars can be set to the same color. Read the documentation above. 
The community will help you but you have posted no source code or attempts.

Comment: I haven’t added the code yet because mine is a webview app all here, now I just want to make it clear to the title bar to set the color of my app webview